# Clear Transients

Tags: transient

I have build a custom theme for a client of mine, and I am using transients in order to make the site operating faster.

After a week, I have see in the wp_options a huge list of transients records (in about 360000 records). This makes me beleave that transients are not removed from the database.

How can I remove that records and how ? Is there any good tutorial ?

Kind regards

Comment: "and I am using transients in order to make the site operating faster" Whaaa...? Please elaborate.

Comment: Agreed, there's little chance that transients are actually making anything any faster for you, especially if you're using them in a way that adds 360k records inside a week. I think you need to re-evaluate whatever it is that you're doing from the start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Unfortunately, expired entries will only be deleted if you attempt to access the transient again. If you don't access the transient then, even though it's expired, WordPress will not remove it. This is [a known "issue"](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/20316) and is due to be corrected at some point in the WordPress core code.

*-Copied from: Artiss Transient Cleaner*

Found this plugin, can help you:

> [Artiss Transient Cleaner](http://wordpress.org/plugins/artiss-transient-cleaner/)

Additionally, can modify the time of the deletion using the process mentioned **[HERE](http://www.stumiller.me/does-wordpress-delete-expired-transients-from-the-database/)**